# How can I make putall and getall methods of a Queue subclass atomic?

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

I have a class that inherits from `Queue`, and is used by another factory class:

```
class myQueue(Queue):
    def putall(self , mobjects , *args):
        self.put(mobject, *args )

    def getall(self , number , *args ):
        return [self.get(*args) for _ in xrange(number)]
```

I use `putall` and `getall` externally, and want them to by atomic. How can I do that? I'm using Python 2.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make `putall` and `getall` atomic, you need to hold a lock that will prevent any other methods that modify the `Queue` from running. The obvious choice would be to use the `mutex` object used internally by `Queue`, but that's implemented using a `threading.Lock`, which means it can't be taken recursively. That means the naive solution will cause a deadlock:

```
from Queue import Queue
import threading

class myQueue(Queue):
    def putall(self , objects , *args):
        with self.mutex:
            for object in objects:
                self.put(object, *args) # This will hang.

    def getall(self , number , *args ):
        with self.mutex:
            return [self.get(*args) for _ in xrange(number)] # This will hang

q = myQueue()
q.putall(["1", "2", "3"])
print(q.getall(2))
```

This will deadlock inside `putall` and `getall`, since both will try to recursively acquire `mutex` (first in `putall`/`getall`, then again in `put`/`get`). You've got a few options to address this. The simplest is to override the `mutex` instance created inside `Queue.__init__` with a `threading.RLock`. This also requires recreating a few other `threading.Condition` objects built using that `mutex`:

```
from Queue import Queue
import threading

class myQueue(Queue):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Queue.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.mutex = threading.RLock()
        self.not_empty = threading.Condition(self.mutex)
        self.not_full = threading.Condition(self.mutex)
        self.all_tasks_done = threading.Condition(self.mutex)

    def putall(self , objects , *args):
        with self.mutex:
            for object in objects:
                self.put(object, *args)

    def getall(self , number , *args ):
        with self.mutex:
            return [self.get(*args) for _ in xrange(number)]

q = myQueue()
q.putall(["1", "2", "3"])

print(q.getall(2))
```

Output:

```
['1', '2']
```

Note that you're relying on implementation details of `Queue` here, which makes this susceptible breaking if the implementation changes in a new version of Python. A more future-proof version of `myQueue` would wrap a `Queue` instance, provide implementations for all its public methods that require a mutex, and use your own recursive lock to synchronize those methods.

Comment: This looks good actually :) overriding the lock to a rlock is brilliance